# How to fix key bindings in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I want to make a sprite move around on the canvas and have tried to use key bindings as controls. When I run the program it doesn't move until I try the correct key. I've tested with mouse buttons and it works fine.

adding code:

```
from tkinter import *

class MainGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.grid = [[""]*15 for n in range(15)]
        self.grid[14][3] = 1
        print(self.grid)
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width = 900, height = 900)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.a, self.b = 45, 175

    def noreaction(self, event):
        print("It clicked")
        print(self.a)
        self.a += 50
        self.b += 50
        self.canvas.create_image(self.a, self.b, image = self.pl, tags = "p2Tag")
        self.canvas.delete("p1Tag")
        self.canvas.tag_bind("p2Tag", "<Key-q>", self.noreaction)

    def run(self):
        self.pl = PhotoImage(file = "player.png")
        self.canvas.create_image(self.a, self.b, image = self.pl, tags = "p1Tag")
        self.canvas.tag_bind("p1Tag", "<Key>", self.noreaction)

        self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1 = -30, 150, 20, 200

        for self.row in self.grid:
            for self.column in self.row:
                self.x0 += 50
                self.x1 += 50

                self.cell = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1)
            self.y0 += 50
            self.y1 += 50
            self.x0 = -30
            self.x1 = 20

root = Tk()
root.focus_set()
obj = MainGame()

obj.run()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of an image. Don't want to re-type all that code.

Comment: Probably the component that you added the binding to does not have focus. Try using `bind_all` at root level.

Comment: Please don't post a link to code on another site. Take the time to post a [mcve] in the question itself. if you're not willing to take the time to write a good question, most people won't be willing to take the time to write a good answer.

Comment: I wanted to test the code so I typed it out for myself. I have added the code to the OPs question so everyone else can use it if they like.

Comment: Hi, sorry I just realized that it would have been more helpful to post the code as text. I'll make sure to do that from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing with your code for a bit it would seam that `tag_bind` only works with mouse clicks. After reviewing all the documentation I could find in `tag_bind` there is nothing that says you can bind a key to a drawn object. So the solution here would be to bind either the root window to the key or to bind the frame the canvas is placed in.

I have changed up your code a little to make this work but it should help you move in the right direction. Without more information as to what you are trying to accomplish in the long run its hard to provide a good answer but I think this will help. Let me know if you have any more questions.

```
from tkinter import *

class MainGame:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid = [[""]*15 for n in range(15)]
        self.grid[14][3] = 1
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, width = 900, height = 900)
        self.canvas.pack()        
        self.a, self.b = 45, 175

    #added an argument here so we can better control the player object.
    def noreaction(self, old):
        print("It clicked")
        print(self.a)
        self.a += 50
        self.b += 50
        self.canvas.delete(old)
        # assigned the object to a class attribute
        self.player_obj = self.canvas.create_image(self.a, self.b, image = self.pl, tags = "p2Tag")
        # you will see <Key-q> and <q> work the same here.
        self.parent.bind("<Key-q>", lambda x: self.noreaction(self.player_obj))

    def run(self):
        self.pl = PhotoImage(file = "./Colors/blk.gif")
        # assigned the object to a class attribute
        self.player_obj = self.canvas.create_image(self.a, self.b, image = self.pl, tags = "p1Tag")
        # you will see <Key-q> and <q> work the same here.
        self.parent.bind("<q>", lambda x: self.noreaction(self.player_obj))


        self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1 = -30, 150, 20, 200
        for self.row in self.grid:
            for self.column in self.row:
                self.x0 += 50
                self.x1 += 50

                self.cell = self.canvas.create_rectangle(self.x0, self.y0, self.x1, self.y1)
            self.y0 += 50
            self.y1 += 50
            self.x0 = -30
            self.x1 + 20

root = Tk()
root.focus_set()
obj = MainGame(root)

obj.run()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think `tag_bind` works for text items. It's just that the other items don't have any way to get keyboard focus.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I was trying to find a way to focus the drawn object but after trying a few things and looking at the docs I don't think there is a way to focus a drawn object either. However what is going on when you bind a mouse click? This works fine but is the mouse click providing focus on the object somehow?

Comment: Mouse clicks are completely unrelated to focus (except for the fact that bindings may change the focus).

Comment: @BryanOakley So when I bind a mouse click to an object what is telling tkinter that the mouse is on that object? In order for a bind to work the focus needs to be on the object that the bind is set to. So how is it that mouse clicks work on the drawn object if clicking does not cause the focus to that drawn object?

Comment: I don't quite know how to answer that. I imagine that tkinter is looking at the pixel under the cursor, and is able to map that to an object since it knows the coordinates of every object. Focus only relates to keyboard events, not mouse events. The computer knows where you clicked, it can't know where you typed. Hence, the focus tells the computer which input element should see the key presses.

Comment: @BryanOakley That makes sense. So with the use of `tag_bind` on the object in question if there is no way for that object to have focus then the binding will never be activated.

Comment: Thanks, It works how I wanted it to now. From why I can understand, I need assign an object to the image and use it in the reaction function. I don't understand why the "parent" means in "self.parent.bind()"

Answer (score -2):

"`<Key>`" is not a valid keysym to bind an event on. Try a valid one, for a full list you can look here http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/keysyms.htm

edit: appears I was mistaken, didn't know it was a valid *event*. You learn something every day :)

Comment: Incorrect. if you `bind("<Key>", some_func)` it will work if any key is pressed. and if you do `"<Key-g>"` it will work for only the letter g lower-case.

Comment: `<Key>` is not a valid _keysym_, but it's a valid event. `<Key>` is a synonym for `<KeyPress>` The canonical documentation is here:  http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm

Comment: your answer implies that `<Key>` is invalid and wont do anything. You need to be more accurate with your statements.